# How to plug the reponse of a django view GET request into the same view as a POST request during testing?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-testing

I have a Django function-based form view that initializes a form with default data on a GET request, and saves the model object on a POST request:

```
def copy(request, ann_id):
    new_ann = get_object_or_404(Announcement, pk=ann_id)
    new_ann.pk = None  # autogen a new primary key (quest_id by default)
    new_ann.title = "Copy of " + new_ann.title
    new_ann.draft = True
    new_ann.datetime_released = new_ann.datetime_released + timedelta(days=7)

    form = AnnouncementForm(request.POST or None, instance=new_ann)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_announcement = form.save(commit=False)
        new_announcement.author = request.user
        new_announcement.datetime_created = timezone.now()
        new_announcement.save()
        form.save()

        return redirect(new_announcement)

    context = {
        "title": "",
        "heading": "Copy an Announcement",
        "form": form,
        "submit_btn_value": "Create",
    }
    return render(request, "announcements/form.html", context)
```

I can't figure out how to test the `form.is_valid()` branch when the form is posted, without manually providing the form data to `self.client.post(url, form_data)` in my view.

Here' what I'm trying:

**test_views.py**

```
class AnnouncementViewTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = ...
        ... etc

    def test_copy_announcement(self):
        # log in a teacher
        success = self.client.login(username=self.test_teacher.username, password=self.test_password)
        self.assertTrue(success)

        # hit the view as a get request first, to load a copy of the announcement in the form
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('announcements:copy', args=[self.test_announcement.id]),
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # The form in this response should be valid, and should bw
        # accepted on a post request, 
        # that is what I am testing in this integration test.

        form_data = response.how_do_get_the_form_data() # ???????

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('announcements:copy', args=[self.test_announcement.id]),
            data=form_data
        )

        # Get the newest announcement just made in the post request
        new_ann = Announcement.objects.latest('datetime_created')

        self.assertRedirects(
            response, 
            new_ann.get_absolute_url()
        )
```

What I want to actually test is that the result of the `get` provides valid default data for the form that can then be submitted via `post` request.

But I can't figure out how to access the form data resulting from the `get` request, so I can then feed it into the form_data provided to the `post` request.

EDIT

I found the location of the form in the get response, but I have no idea how to get that in code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the response form in this way:

```py
response.context['form']
```

From here you can build your payload in this way:

```py
retrieved_instance = response.context['form'].instance
form_data = dict(title=retrieved_instance.title, ... <all the other fields>)
response = self.client.post(
            reverse('announcements:copy', args=[self.test_announcement.id]),
            data=form_data)
        )
```

This is not like resubmitting the page but is very similar because you're resubmitting the same form.

Actually, your test seems more like an e2e test (when speaking about integrations and e2e there is some ambiguity let's say), for this reason, if I were you, I would switch "tool" and use selenium to simulate a user interaction from the beginning (open an existing announcement) to the end, pressing the submit button on your web page.

**Only in this way what you're submitting is the "real" response of the "get"**

If you are new to this kind of test, you can find here a simple tutorial https://lincolnloop.com/blog/introduction-django-selenium-testing/ to understand the main concepts.

Comment: is there a way to just copy the `retrieved_instance` field values into a dict without listing all the fields manually?

Comment: you can use `response.context['form'].initial`, that is a dict, instead of `response.context['form'].instance`

Comment: This is so close!  `initial` can almost be plugged in directly, except that it includes some values like `None` that the post request complains about.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit confusing but I will try to head you in right direction.

To clean-up the code you should use **Class Based View** where you can use your form easily anywhere. A sample code I just wrote:

```
class TestView(View):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = 'home' # dummy view
    context = {"form": myform()} 
    # myform is the definition/class of your form which contains all attrs.

    def get(self, request):
        context = self.context
        context['form'] = form # fill out your data here for get request
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):
        context=self.context 
    # self.context certain that you're using exact form which you defined in class-scope
        form=context['form']
        # Form Validation
        if form.is_valid():
            #perform any logical validations here and save the form if required
        return redirect(self.success_url)

        context = self.context
        context['form'] = form # just to show you that you can access that form anywhere
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, this question IS confusing now that I look at it again.  I'm actually wanting to test this view in an integration test.  I will add to it.

Comment: But this is super helpful anyway, thank you.  I've struggled to switch to CBVs!

Comment: Yes but once you are comfortable with CBV they will make your life hell easy. Glad I could give you some idea. If your question dont need to be answer now please confirm my answer and close this. Thanks!

Comment: It still needs an answer.  The question is about the integration test.

Answer (score 0):

You coul manually pass data to you form like this and test the `is_valid` function in a unit test:

```
form_data = {'my': 'value', 'form': 'value', 'fields': 'value'}
form = AnnouncementForm(form_data)
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid)
```

Comment: I'm going for an integration test here. And as mentioned in the question: "...without manually providing the form data".  I've clarified the question with some more info.